# How to get a draw of variable from Probability density function?

Tags: matlab

I have a real data matrix of size `13x200`, which contains the readings of `N=13` sensors along `T=200` time instances. I want to model each row of reading with a Gaussian model.

So, for each sensor `i=1,...N` (for each row of the matrix) I compute the mean and the variance, then I compute the probability density function (PDF) of that data vector which will get the size `1xT`.

I want to get a draw of 200 Gaussian samples from that PDF vector. How can I do that with MATLAB?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the stuff you already tried for a better question quality. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894953/matlab-generate-random-numbers-from-custom-made-probability-density-function/47938722#47938722)

Comment: Are you sure that drawing 200 gaussians will give an informative display...?

Comment: @Adiel I think the OP means to draw a random value from the distribution (as in take), not to draw the distribution (as in create a graphic display)

Comment: @Adiel, In fact, I am implementing an algorithm that resolves the completion matrix but it has not worked well with the actual data I have and I doubt that it is because of the fact that these data do not follow exactly a Gaussian model and I would like from this draw to confirm this idea.

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is your standard deviation and `m` is your mean, you can get `N` random values from the Guassian distribution like so:

```
v = randn(N,1) * s + m;
```

Drawing random values from a measured PDF is more finicky. You start by computing the cumulative distribution:

```
cpdf = cumsum(pdf);
cpdf = cpdf / max(cpdf); % make sure it's normalized
```

Then you draw a value between 0 and 1, uniformly distributed, and look for the bin where this value is first reached:

```
p = rand(1);
c = find(cpdf >= p, 1, 'first');
```

Ideally you'd use interpolation to get the exact location where the CPDF crosses the chosen value. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. ;)

---

**Edit**

This is not what you're asking, but what I think you need. You're computing 200 values of a PDF from 200 samples. That makes no sense. You cannot model a PDF sufficiently accurately this way, the random samples drawn will simply mirror your input values.

If you want to draw 200 random values that are close to your 200 input samples, do this:

```
data + randn(size(data)) * s;
```

Where you pick `s` to be small w.r.t. the standard deviation of your data. Maybe you need a different `s` per row.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use the PDF is that I would like to get values that are close to the old values but that all follow together, at the same time, a Gaussian model

Comment: @Manel I was still editing the answer when you posted. I wrote how to get values from a measured PDF also. But you question is not worded right, it is rather ambiguous which of the two methods I described you're after.

Comment: @Manel Another edit, with what I think you are really after.

Comment: thank you for responding, as for the interpolation , does the interp1 matlab function is the needed one ?

Comment: @Manel yes, it is.